# Get-or-create pattern in Java 7?

Tags: java, multithreading, lazy-initialization

I am trying to write a generic functionality that does thread-safe optional lazy initialization on demand. I cannot use the standard pattern, as the value is not final and could have been set via a setter already.

In Java 8 I solved that by writing a generic `LazyInitializer` with a supplier:

```
public class LazyInitializer<T> {

  protected final Supplier<T> initializer;
  protected AtomicReference<T> value = new AtomicReference<>();

  public LazyInitializer(final Supplier<T> initializer) {
    this.initializer = initializer;
  }

  public T get() {
    T result = this.value.get();
    if (result == null) {
      this.value.compareAndSet(null, this.initializer.get());
      result = this.value.get();
    }
    return result;
  }

  public void setValue(final T value) {
    this.value.set(value);
  }

}
```

You would then use this class like this:

```
final LazyInitializer<List<String>> value = new LazyInitializer<>(ArrayList<String>::new);
```

This is thread-safe, can handle setters, has a very low overhead and especially: requires little boilerplate code.

Now however I am forced to use Java 7 and I cannot seem to find an equally elegant solution, as Java 7 cannot use Suppliers and therefore requires to write a lot of ugly code. Also generics do not allow to instanciate them unless you supply the exact class, which is a problem if you use generic class values (like `ArrayList<String>`).

As far as I can tell I am either forced to write ugly code or do reflection magic beyond my capabilites, or is there any way to write the `LazyInitializer` class in an elegant way in Java 7 that I am missing?

**Edit:** Using the Answer from Jorn Vernee I modified the class to work with Java 7 as follows:

```
public class LazyInitializer<T> {

  protected final Class<?> clazz;
  protected AtomicReference<T> value = new AtomicReference<>();

  public LazyInitializer(final Class<?> clazz) {
    this.clazz = clazz;
  }

  public T get() {
    T result = this.value.get();
    if (result == null) {
      this.value.compareAndSet(null, constructNew());
      result = this.value.get();
    }
    return result;
  }

  public void setValue(final T value) {
    this.value.set(value);
  }

  protected T constructNew() {
    try {
      return (T) clazz.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Which can then be (once again) elegantly called like this:

```
final LazyInitializer<List<String>> value = new LazyInitializer<>(ArrayList.class);
```

**However** this class can no longer verify if the supplied class actually matches (because Generics) and it only works with default constructors. But at least it solves my case.

Comment: Am I wrong or may you skip the first `this.value.get()` and the if-clause in your Java8 example code?

Comment: In the case that `value == null` the value should be set to the initial value. So no, you cannot skip that.

Comment: @TwoThe Am I mistaken or your code can actually trigger supplier execution more than once? Since parameter evaluation for `compareAndSet` is not atomic with the function itself.

Comment: @chimmi you are right. Maybe using `AtomicReference.updateAndGet(UnaryOperator<V> updateFunction)` instead would solve the problem. But the comparison `currentValue == null` then would be part of the `UnaryOperator`.

Comment: That is not the question, but anyways: in worst case the supplier.get method could be called multiple times (but that is not a concern for me), yet the value is only set once. This is important because between the `== null` check and the `compareAndSet` another thread could call the `set` function and set `value` to something other than null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nice things about lambdas/method refs, is that it reduced the amount of code by X. So if you go back, of course, it's going to increase the amount of code by X again. If you need to wrap any code in a functor, an anonymous class is the best way to do it imho.

There is another less efficient, hackier way to do this that uses reflection. And as long as you use it as intended, it will not throw exceptions.

You can do a dynamic constructor lookup, you'd still need the `Supplier` type:

```
interface Supplier<T> {
    T get();
}
```

Then you have a factory method that does the lookup at runtime:

```
public static <T> Supplier<T> constructorLookup(Class<?> rawtype) {
    try {
        Constructor<?> cons = rawtype.getConstructor();

        return new Supplier<T>() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public T get() {
                try {
                    return (T) cons.newInstance();
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                        | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                }
            }               
        };

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
    }       
}
```

The resulting code would look like:

```
LazyInitializer<List<String>> value 
    = new LazyInitializer<>(constructorLookup(ArrayList.class));
```

Currently this only works for default constructors, but could be expanded to work with arguments too.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/), you could use its latest Java-7-compatible version which contains a `Supplier` class, which in turn has the same signature as Java 8's `Supplier`. Only the import is different: `com.google.common.base.Supplier` instead of `java.util.function.Supplier`.

If you don't want to use Guava, you could still write your own `Supplier` with the same signatures as Java 8's `Supplier`:

```
public interface Supplier<T> {
  T get();
}
```

Then, whichever `Supplier` you use, you can write the following:

```
Supplier<List<String>> stringListSupplier = new Supplier<List<String>>() {
  @Override public List<String> get() { return new ArrayList<>(); }
};
```

If the generics bother you that much, you can actually write the following, and then reuse it at will.

```
public static <T> Supplier<List<T>> newArrayListSupplier() {
  return new Supplier<List<T>>() {
    @Override public List<T> get() { return new ArrayList<>(); }
  };
}
```

Your final code then becomes:

```
final LazyInitializer<List<String>> value = new LazyInitializer<>(MyClass.<String>newArrayListSupplier());
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint, however this does not solve my issue, as I especially want to reduce the amount of code. I have several places where values are lazy-set in JSON-POJO objects and doing all that with anonymous classes would tripple the amount of code I currently have. And since all those places have different classes I cannot use your solution for Lists.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry to tell you then that there is no other way to lazily instanciate new objects. Such a pattern is required to simulate lambdas (which is in the end your request).